# How to run a method asynchronously

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code to detect faces and draw a square around them:

```
import cv2
import mtcnn

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
detector = mtcnn.MTCNN()

def face_detection(frame):
    faces = detector.detect_faces(frame)
    if(len(faces) == 0):
        return

    x, y, w, h = faces[0]['box']

    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

while True:
    _, frame = cam.read()
    face_detection(frame)
        
    cv2.imshow('Camera Feed', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
```

It works well, the problem is that the mtcnn takes a while to run, and so the framerate is very low, because it waits the face_detection method to show a new frame, in a asyncronous programming language like Dart I can put face_detection to run asynchronously and not wait on it, then the frames keep updating on the screen and when face_detection returns something, it will be drawn, keeping the last square drawn when computing the next. Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Check this [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: @pizoooo I took a look on this lib, but all that I found keeps waiting on the methods to finish, and also needed to be an async function, but my detector.detect_faces(frame) isn't, so I couldn't find a way to solve the problem